# Automatically call decorated functions

Tags: typescript, decorator

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
export class MyClass {
    public constructor() {
        this.doStuff1AtStartup();
        this.doStuff2AtStartup();
    }

    private doStuff1AtStartup(): void {
        // Do something here
    }

    private doStuff2AtStartup(): void {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

However, this becomes very tedious If I need to add a few more functions and call them inside the constructor. As a result, I've tried to create decorators for my functions, remove the calls from the constructor and instead call the function inside my decorator function.

```
export class MyClass {
    @DecoratorWhichCallsMyClassAtStartup()
    private doStuffAtStartup() {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

I can't figure out, though, how to keep the context (using this.something always returns undefined) - I figure that's because I'm now calling the function from my decorator function and thus can't get the reference to the class instance from there. I've also tried to call the original function by using `bind` or `apply`, but couldn't get it to work.

Can someone please suggest an implementation for this kind of thing?

Comment: God this unholy snippet works: https://tsplay.dev/whywasicreatedthisway001 - I don't think this is possible with conventional methods because in the decorator you get the target as the class itself which means you can't really change the class constructor.

Comment: You will probably have more luck using a wrapper function that extends the given class

Comment: Correction: it is possible using class decorators: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators). Fabricating an answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), I've come up with this:

```
function AutoCall(methods: string[]) {
    return function <T extends { new (...args: any[]): any }>(constructor: T) {
        return class extends constructor {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                super(...args);

                for (const method of methods) {
                    super[method]();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Pay attention to this line:

> If the class decorator returns a value, it will replace the class declaration with the provided constructor function.

This lets us do what we want! We can replace the constructor with one that calls the methods automatically for us.

And that's exactly what this decorator should do. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to make it take keys of the class it is called on, so I had to use `string[]` here as the type for `methods`.

Ideally it should also check if `super[method]` is an actual function, too.

Here's an example usage as well:

```
@AutoCall(["method"])
class MyClass {
    private method() {
        console.log("i was called");
    }
}

new MyClass(); // logs "i was called"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQRFOBhAhgGxwCgFsBTKACzgBMBnALkWqgCcYwBzAbQF0BKRAbwCwAKERjETUiCZJQkWAkQAeACqJiADyjEwNAYjDEA7onwA6C1iZs6iLGACe3HvXsPEAXwB8+CAkZMINBwTPQqfEKi4tGSUNJIEDhY1NTqWjp6fmABQehMAiLRReJZOcFM5pbWtm7OBVHFjQwgAA7EFRZmVjY8ANwihU2NwCGmpVCIJORUiHDAk6QUNBGDQ0PUre0cU0tc+H2ra+Ieh00nDUXn0R79wuciAAKo6Nh4+BwARDtUH7wiiclUgBZBwYJIperRFosABuWG0C2mlH2kMapTgOGIZhwcDY+A+MEQRmSiAguExlA+Bwu53uwkMJhBYMB+yAA)

Comment: Is there any way I could do this without specifying an array of method names, but instead having it retrieve the decorated functions' names by itself?

Comment: Oh yeah certainly; I believe method decorators are evaluated before class decorators, so you would use a map of classes to decorate properties and in the class decorator call the marked properties from the map.

Comment: I've done this to do the thing I mentioned: [Playground](https://codesandbox.io/embed/typescript-forked-5lblvv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Does this look like a good approach? Would there be a better solution to this?

Comment: @Radu It works, but that means you can only use it on one class. If you instead had a map of classes to an array of properties, then it would work on multiple. Here is an example implementation of [that](https://tsplay.dev/NBjapN)